# qemu, kvm: Guest: No DHCPOFFERS received

Tags: networking, dhcp, kvm-virtualization, bridge, qemu

I'm trying to set up a **virtual machine** (guest) wich should act as router (ubntu 14.04). The host is a CentOS 7 machine (4x LAN). The ***guest* should get a public ip** address over it's `eth0` (*guest*), wich is connected to `enp0s20f0` (*host*) over `br0` (*host*).

The **Problem** is, that the ***guest* doesn't get an ip** address.

---

**More informations:**

- All interfaces of the *host* (`enp0s20f0` - `enp0s20f3`) are connected over bridges `br0` - `br3` (*host*) to `eth0` - `eth3` (*guest*).
- The LAN interfaces (host) don't have a *bootproto*
- The bridges (*host*) don't have a *bootproto*, except `br2`: there is `bootproto=static` so I can connect the *host* to the *guest* and then to the internet

---

**Sketch:**

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|host: CentOS 7, KVM, qemu                                                                                |
|  +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+  + - - - - - -+ |
|  |guest (VM): ubuntu 14.04 router, firewall                                           |  |other guests  |
|  |                                                                                    |       (VM)    | |
|  | +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ |  |              |
|  | |                                                                                | |               | |
|  | |                                     firewall                                   | |  |              |
|  | |                                                                                | |               | |
|  | ++------------+---------+-------------+-------+-------------+------+------------++ |  |              |
|  |  +------------+         +-------------+       +-------------+      +------------+  |               | |
|  |  |PROBLEM:    |         |             |       |             |      |            |  |  |              |
|  |  |eth0        |         |eth1         |       |eth2         |      |eth3        |  |  + - - - - - -+ |
|  |  |dhcp        |         |static       |       |static       |      |static      |  |      X          |
|  +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+    X            |
|     |not working |         |lan zone     |       |dmz          |      |wlan zone   |     X              |
|     +----+-------+         +-----+-------+       +-------+-----+      +-----------++   X                |
|          |                       |                       |                        |  X                  |
|          |                       |                       |             X  X  X  X |X                    |
|   +------+---------+       +-----+------------+        +-+-------------X--+      ++-----------------+   |
|   |                |       |                  |        |                  |      |                  |   |
|   |                |       |                  |        |                  |      |                  |   |
|   |     br0        |       |      br1         |        |    br2           |      |      br3         |   |
|   |                |       |                  |        | BOOTPROTO=static |      |                  |   |
|   |  BOOTPROTO=none|       | BOOTPROTO=none   |        | IP: a local ip   |      |  BOOTPROTO=none  |   |
|   +-------+--------+       +---------+--------+        +----------+-------+      +---------+--------+   |
|           |                          |                            |                        |            |
|           |                          |                            |                        |            |
|           |                          |                            |                        |            |
|   +-------+--------+       +---------+--------+        +----------+-------+      +---------+--------+   |
|   |                |       |                  |        |                  |      |                  |   |
|   |enp0s20f0       |       |enp0s20f1         |        |enp0s20f2         |      |enp0s20f3         |   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |                |       |                  |        |                  |      |                  |    
    |                |       |                  |        |                  |      |                  |    
    +--------X-------+       +---------X--------+        +---------XX-------+      +----------XX------+    
             XXXXX                     X                            XXXXXX                      XX         
                 XX  loc LAN  XXX      X           other server (dmz)    XXX     wlan zone       XX        
                  X             XXXXXXXX                      X       XXXXXX        XXX           X        
     internet XXXXX                                           XXXXXXXXX               XXXXXXXXX XXX
```

---

**Configs:**

*Guest:*

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
#[...] lo [...]
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# The lan
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.x.y
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.x.255

# the dmz
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
        address 10.0.p.q
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 10.0.p.255

# The wirelles zone
auto eth3
iface eth3 inet static
        address 192.168.v.w
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.v.255
```

*Host:*

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*

NAME=br0                    DEVICE=br0                  NAME=br2                   NAME=br3                
TYPE=Bridge                 NAME=br1                    TYPE=Bridge                TYPE=Bridge             
ONBOOT=yes                  TYPE=Bridge                 BOOTPROTO=static           ONBOOT=yes              
BOOTPROTO=none              ONBOOT=yes                  ONBOOT=yes                 BOOTPROTO=none          
NM_CONTROLLED=no            BOOTPROTO=none              IPADDR=10.0.0.10           NM_CONTROLLED=no        
DELAY=0                     NM_CONTROLLED=no            NETMASK=255.255.255.0      DELAY=0                 
DEFROUTE=no                 DELAY=0                     GATEWAY=10.0.p.q           DEFROUTE=no             
PEERDNS=no                  DEFROUTE=no                 DNS1=10.0.p.q              PEERDNS=no              
# PEERROUTES=yes            PEERDNS=no                  NM_CONTROLLED=no           # PEERROUTES=yes        
# IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no     # PEERROUTES=yes            DELAY=0                    # IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no 
# IPV6INIT=no               # IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no     DEFROUTE=yes               # IPV6INIT="no"         
# IPV6_AUTOCONF=no          # IPV6INIT=no               PEERDNS=yes                # IPV6_AUTOCONF=no      
# IPV6_DEFROUTE=no          # IPV6_AUTOCONF=no          # PEERROUTES=yes           # IPV6_DEFROUTE=no      
# IPV6_PEERDNS=no           # IPV6_DEFROUTE=no          # IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no    # IPV6_PEERDNS=no       
# IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes       # IPV6_PEERDNS=no           # IPV6INIT=no              # IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes   
# IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no     # IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes       # IPV6_AUTOCONF=no         # IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no 
DEVICE=br0                  # IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no     # IPV6_DEFROUTE=no         DEVICE=br3              
                            DEVICE=br1                  # IPV6_PEERDNS=no                                  
                                                        # IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes                              
                                                        #IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no                             
                                                        DEVICE=br2                                         

NAME=enp0s20f0              NAME=enp0s20f1              NAME=enp0s20f2             NAME=enp0s20f3          
HWADDR="ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:kl"  HWADDR=ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:mn    HWADDR=ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:op   HWADDR=ab:cd:ef:gh:ij:qr
UUID="[...]"                UUID=[...]                  UUID=[...]                 UUID=[...]              
TYPE=Ethernet               TYPE=Ethernet               TYPE=Ethernet              TYPE=Ethernet           
BOOTPROTO=none              BOOTPROTO=none              BOOTPROTO=none             BOOTPROTO=none          
ONBOOT=yes                  ONBOOT=yes                  ONBOOT=yes                 ONBOOT=yes              
BRIDGE=br0                  BRIDGE=br1                  BRIDGE=br2                 BRIDGE=br3              
NM_CONTROLLED=no            NM_CONTROLLED=no            NM_CONTROLLED=no           NM_CONTROLLED=no        
# PERSISTENT_DHCLIENT=1     # DEFROUTE=no               # DEFROUTE=no              # DEFROUTE=no           
# DEFROUTE=no               # PEERDNS=yes               # PEERDNS=yes              # PEERDNS=yes           
# PEERDNS=yes               # PEERROUTES=yes            # PEERROUTES=yes           # PEERROUTES=yes        
# PEERROUTES=yes            # IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no     # IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no    # IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no 
# IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes    # IPV6INIT="no"             # IPV6INIT=no              # IPV6INIT=no           
# IPV6INIT=no               # IPV6_AUTOCONF=no          # IPV6_AUTOCONF=no         # IPV6_AUTOCONF=no      
# IPV6_AUTOCONF=no          # IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes         # IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes        # IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes     
# IPV6_DEFROUTE=no          # IPV6_PEERDNS=yes          # IPV6_PEERDNS=yes         # IPV6_PEERDNS=yes      
# IPV6_PEERDNS=yes          # IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes       # IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes      # IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes   
# IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes       # IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no     # IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no    # IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no 
# IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no     DEVICE=enp0s20f1            DEVICE=enp0s20f2           DEVICE=enp0s20f3        
DEVICE=enp0s20f0
```

---

- **All `ip route` and all `ifconfig` / `ip addr` are returning the correct values, except for `eth0` (*guest*).**
- On running `ifup eth0` the *guest* trys to get an ip address (`DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval [...]`) and ens with `No DHCPOFFERS received.`

---

I'm happy about every idea...

Comment: Does your ISP actually provide a public IP via DHCP over Ethernet? If you unplug the cable into `enp0s20f0` and plug that cable into something else which requests a DHCP address, does it work?

Comment: Ah yes my ISP gives me a public IP over DHCP and this works on other devices and even on the host system, when I use a apt network-script for ```enp0s20f0```

Comment: If you don't intend for the interface to be configured with its own IP on the _host_, then you should use macvtap instead of a bridge.

Comment: No Michael, he was just testing on the host. He wants the public IP to be on the router VM.

Comment: It's possble that your ISP's device doesn't give DHCP addresses to a MAC address which is not directly connected to it. You'd need to call your ISP to confirm this. If so, you could use ebtables to spoof the MAC of the VM, like this: https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. @suprjami: this sounds good. I'll check this soon and report the result ;) @ MichaelHampton: I didn't heared of macvtap before. I'll test this if it isn't the mac-problem

Comment: @suprjami: Thank you :D I never would have thought of something like that. How can I thank you? :D

I edited the vm via virsh and wrote the LAN interfaces MAC address into the guests bridge with virsh. After some reboots and reconnects it worked :D

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it's all working fine. I added my comment as an Answer, feel free to mark its as correct and upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possble that your ISP's device doesn't give DHCP addresses to a MAC address which is not directly connected to it. You'd need to call your ISP to confirm this.

If so, you could use ebtables to spoof the MAC of the VM, like this:

http://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections